# Power supply needs BASED on usage plus 35%

Tags: power, inverter, 12v

I'm DIY'ing a RV van. What is the best power supply setup for a 8kW maxed out load plus 30%? I realize that this is a lot of power. I am trying to keep it self-contained and self-powered.

Current Power items:

```
4kW Peak Inverter(2k steady)
1kW Peak Inverter(500 steady)
Two-Sealed lead acid farm batteries
100W solar panel
100A MPPT Charge controller
10A Battery Maintainer
200/300A Fuses (ON ALL BATTERY CABLING)
```

Intended 120V Power Usage Items:

```
-Mini Fridge: 4A Start/1.8A Run @ low *24hrs
-Coffee pot/oven: 15A(1500W)*3hrs
-LCD monitor: 2.1A(200W)*12hrs
-Laptop: 7.7A(AC plugged in)*10hrs
-TV Box: 2A*7hrs
-Hotplate: 9A*3hrs
-Corded drill: 5.5A(used when necessary only)
-Major power tools: x4 12A(used when necessary only)
-AC Unit: 4A(455W)*10hrs (hot days only)
```

My watt calc runs just under 8kW with all items and tools plugged and running. 5kW max appliances/electronics and 3.9kW "basic items needed" running at 80%.

```
A) 1k inverter: TV, monitor, laptop, water pump / heater.
B) Appliances and tools
```

Could someone please suggest reasonable case battery setup to accomplish this?

Comment: I'd suggest using a propane stove/oven, and possibly fridge.

Comment: And a bunch of those other loads would be better run off 12 or 24V.

Comment: Not sure what use you can make of the 100W solar panel.